# Wordpress - call the functions in specific order

Tags: wordpress

I am using the Wordpress Yet Another Related Posts Plugin to display the related posts in the RSS Feed. I also want to add additional info to the footer of RSS. However, the information that I add using add_filter() in functions.php is showing above the related posts. I want it ti display after the related posts. I concluded that the functions from the WP plugins are called after the ones from functions.php.

Is there a way to change that? I just don't want to edit the YARPP plugin to add my info. I want to make the change the professional way.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

`add_filter` takes $priority as a third argument. From the [codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_filter):

> Used to specify the order in which the functions associated with a particular action are executed. Lower numbers correspond with earlier execution, and functions with the same priority are executed in the order in which they were added to the action.

The default priority is 10, so assuming the YARPP plugin also uses `add_filter`, set your priority to higher than 10 and it should appear after.

Comment: Thanks, that solved my problem. It uses 600 as the third parameter.